# error: The format of value 'application/json; charset=utf-8' is invalid. from webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, utf-8

I am using webapi in my mvc project and when ever I made a request from browser to api call I am getting the following error:

And i am using the .netFramework 4.0

Exception Details:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The format of value 'application/json; charset=utf-8' is invalid.

Description:

```
  An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
  request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the 
  error and where it originated in the code.
```

Exception Details:

```
  System.FormatException: The format of value 'application/json; 
  charset=utf-8' is invalid.
```

Source Error:

```
  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current 
  web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the 
  exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
        [FormatException: The format of value 'application/json; charset=utf-8' 
        is invalid.]
        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.CheckMediaTypeFormat(String 
        mediaType, String parameterName) +119919
        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue..ctor(String mediaType) +23
        System.Net.Http.ObjectContent.BuildHeaderValue(String mediaType) +63
        System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1..ctor(T value, MediaTypeFormatter 
        formatter, String mediaType) +66
        System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, HttpConfiguration configuration) +892
        System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value) +104
        System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.HandleException(HttpRequestMessage request, Exception exception, HttpConfiguration configuration) +191
        System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +284
        System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +41
        System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +347
        System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +55
        System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContextBase, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +316
        System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +77
        System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
        System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I searched in google but can't find the proper solution.

Comment: You are not showing your code.

Comment: Thanks for all. I had Resolved my issue by updating my Net.http and web.http dll version from 4.0.0.0 to 5.2.0.0